# Why is the state mutating if I am using spread operator?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have this code that I am testing on jsfiddle

```
onVote = (dir, index) => {        
    console.log(this.state)

    const products = [...this.state.products]           
    products[index].votes = dir ? products[index].votes + 1 : products[index].votes - 1

    console.log(this.state.products[index].votes)
    // this.setState({products})
  };
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hkL3wug7/2/

However, even though I am not setting State, the console log shows that the state is changes every time I click on the plus and minus signs.

I did the same as in this article https://medium.com/@giltayar/immutably-setting-a-value-in-a-js-array-or-how-an-array-is-also-an-object-55337f4d6702

```
const newState = [...state] // clone the array
      newState[action.index].done = true
      return newState
```

as far as I understand

(it is not duplicate of the other question, I am not asking for an efficient way)

Comment: That's a shallow copy of the list structure. That doesn't make copies of the elements it contains. You'll need to make copies of them somehow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @Carcigenicate mentioned, you have created a shallow copy of the array which means you have a new array pointing to the same objects in the original.

To avoid mutating the original object, you will need to also create a copy of the one you would like to mutate, e.g.:

```
// Shallow copy of the array
const products = [...this.state.products];

// Shallow copy of the object within the array
const updatedProduct = { ...products[index] };

// Update the copy of the object
updatedProduct.votes = dir ? updatedProduct.votes + 1 : updatedProduct.votes - 1;

// Replace the object with the updated copy
products[index] = updatedProduct;
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Carcigenicate mentioned in the comment, using the spread operator creates a shallow copy of the array.  This is creating a problem for you because the expanded version of the array contains `Object`s which are passed by reference.  So even though your local variable `products` is a new copy of `this.state.products`, they both contain references to the same `Object`s.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you would have to clone the objects in `this.state.products`.  One possible way to do this is using `Object.assign` and replace your `const products =  [...this.state.products]` with:

```
const products = [
    Object.assign({}, this.state.products.Orange),
    Object.assign({}, this.state.products.Apples),
    Object.assign({}, this.state.products.Bananas)
]
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now